# Solution to content jumping with elements with different heights?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a common issue and I'm not sure there's a good solution to this? Maybe with javascript somehow?

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/8mf7qy5e/1/

When you click the 'change results' button I'm testing in loading new results which you might see in an app loading new data.

You'll notice the content underneath (black box) jumps because the results return data with different lengths i.e the original results have more results and thus the content jumps depending on how much content there are.

I could set a min-height but then I'll have loads of white-space underneath the results with not as many results.

Is a solid solution to this issue?

Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <button id="btn-results">Change results</button>
    <div class="results-content">
        <div class="results-a">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="results-b">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item col-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, reprehenderit.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Base */
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Content */
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
}

.content-wrapper {
    display: block;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Grid */

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.grid-item {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

/* Results */
.results-content {
    padding: 50px;
}

.results-b {
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
    $('#btn-results').on('click', function(){
        $('.results-a').toggle();
        $('.results-b').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: precisely what do u means by "content jumps". are u referring to the spacing below the content?

Comment: _What_ is the desired behaviour? There could be dozens of solutions...

Comment: how you want it to behave ... the jump is normal in your case, you may consider animation if you want it to go smoothly

Comment: are you loking somthing like 'slideToggle'? https://jsfiddle.net/8mf7qy5e/2/